# What does 'Broadcast to LAN' mean and why is it important?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

My multiplayer doesn't work even when it says that I have it turned on. I'm not sure about some of the settings though, for example, what does 'Broadcast to LAN' mean and why is it important?

Comment: 'Broadcast to LAN' tells the game to let other computers on the **L**ocal **A**rea **N**etwork (LAN) know that there is a Minecraft multiplayer game available. That way, other Minecraft players on the same home network as you will see the game pop up on their copy of Minecraft

Answer (score 2):

It means that other Minecraft players on the same wifi network can play in your world with you. By enabling this option you can allow the multiplayer experience without a dedicated server.